# How to use na.omit with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, facet-wrap

[image: Database]

The image shows the database, it starts with day 0 and ends with day 14. In between these, there are empty values for what I am plotting. I am unable to correctly use na.omit().

What I get currently is this:

[image: Current graph]

As you can see, half of it should not be there. So i could limit the axis to show only part of it, But i might have data every other day. So omitting NAs is the best option. The code is as follows:

```
T <- USP20019 %>%
ggplot(aes(Cell_line, Capsids)) +
geom_col(aes(fill=Day), size=1.1, position = 'dodge2') +
facet_wrap(Condition~., scales = 'free_x') +
ylab('Titer mg/L') +
xlab('Time (Day)') +
ggtitle('All data') +
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `subset` inside `ggplot2`.

```
T <- ggplot(subset(USP20019, !is.na(Capsids)) , aes(Cell_line, Capsids)) + ...
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a prize. I only had to subset it and create a new dataframe, and them the excat same code with the new one :D thanks a lot!